# can I use elasticsearch for star schema?

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

is elasticsearch good for starschema? I will query relationships in different collections, counts, joins, etc...

or elasticsearch is only good for storing object docs, and the relationship I need use another database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think elasticsearch is not suitable for your requirements.  Elasticsearch search support for aggregation, count, parent child relationship etc..  It is best for storing docs. But it won support joins Nd other Sql features.. 
You better change the scheme as for NOSQL or go for Sql database..